# Receving oauth 2.0 401 error when trying to retrieve token with authorization code

Tags: vb.net, oauth-2.0

I am trying to retrieve an authorization code for a token but keep getting a 401 error. I get the authorization code from my callbackUrl.

It believe I am sending the request properly. I am sending a base64 Bearer token in the authorization header using my key:secret. I am just not sure what to do from here to resolve things. I am new to oauth so I don't know if there is a way for me to determine the problem from my end of things? I'm completely stumped...

```
[callbackUrl]/?scope=READ&state=test&code=98LtBkcY

https://www.[testapi].net/v1/id/oauth/access_token?grant_type=authorization_code&code=98LtBkcY
```

Error:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: application/json
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="null",error='invalid_token",error_description='keymanagement.service.invalid_access_token: Invalid Access Token"
Content-Length: 116

{"fault":{"faultstring":"Invalid Access Token","detail":{"errorcode":"keymanagement.service.invalid_access_token"}}}
```

I'm working in VB.NET and creating my bearer token like this:
Authorization_Token = `System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ConsumerKey & ":" & ConsumerSecret)).ToString`

Comment: @JosVinke Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. Their  documentation told me to use the token as a Bearer token but tried it and worked with out it.